# Тень на css: только справа и слева

Tags: html, css

```
background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Для Firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Для Safari и Chrome */
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Параметры тени */
padding: 10px;
```

Представьте себе обычную тень вокруг div. Нагуглить - минута. Можно ли сделать тень только справа и слева?

Comment: "Справа" и "слева" пишутся слитно в данном случае.

Comment: Ты чертовски прав! Переписал )

Comment: Еще в заголовке исправь, будет вообще красота, вах!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстрое [гугление](https://www.google.lv/search?q=css+box-shadow+left+right) привело [на самую первую выдачу результатов](http://tiffanyong.blogspot.com/2012/02/box-shadow-on-right-and-left-only.html).

Comment: Да, на английском реально находит!

Answer (score 3):

Можно, например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/dc3vD/).

Comment: Эм.. так то да, уже шаг в перед, только вот я указал тень с градиентом. В этом то и проблема

http://jsfiddle.net/dc3vD/5/

Answer (score 3):

Разве что используя overflow;
html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.shadow {
    width:100px; height: 100px; 
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.content {
    width:110px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Stillborn, тоже копал в эту сторону, правда не помогло http://jsfiddle.net/dc3vD/6/

Или как то не так применил

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VuUKK/1/
не так применил
у тебя content меньше shadow, а должно быть наоборот.
Почитай про overflow